# Create a simple ToDo application which would be able to add, delete and update ToDo with spring boot starter web.But update scenario is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

Below is the todo controller which i am using to add,delete and update todo.This is simple spring boot application for which i am using sprint boot starter web.

TodoController

```
    package com.Mayur.Controller;

    import com.Mayur.Model.Todo;
    import com.Mayur.Service.ToDoService;
    import com.Mayur.Service.ValidationCheck;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.validation.Valid;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes("name")
    public class ToDoController {
        private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ToDoController.class);

        @Autowired
        ToDoService todd;

        @InitBinder
        public void init(WebDataBinder web)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            web.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,new CustomDateEditor(sdf,false));
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "/listtodos")
        public String listTodos(ModelMap m) {
            List<Todo> todos = todd.retrieveToDo();
            String kk =(String)m.get("name");
            m.put("l",kk);
            m.put("td",todos);
            return "listtodos";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value ="/addTodo")
        public String addTodo(ModelMap map){
            map.put("todo",new Todo(0,(String)map.get("name"),"",new Date(),false));
            return "addTodo";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value ="/addTodo",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addTodoNew(ModelMap map, @Valid Todo tod, BindingResult bindingResult){
            System.out.println("server restarted");
            if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
            {
                return "/addTodo";
            }
            System.out.println("Tod is :"+tod);
            List<Todo> tdlist= todd.addTodo(tod);
            map.put("addList",tdlist);
            return "redirect:/listtodos";
        }

       @RequestMapping(value="/delete")
       public String delete(@RequestParam int id,ModelMap m)
       {
           List<Todo> tdlist = todd.retrieveToDo();
           log.info(tdlist);
           tdlist.removeIf(i->i.getId()==id);
           m.put("td",tdlist);
           m.put("message","Deleted Sucessfully");
           log.info(tdlist);
           return "listtodos";
       }

       @RequestMapping(value="/update")
        public String updateTodo(@RequestParam int id,Model m)
       {
           m.addAttribute("registerId",id);
           return "updateTodo";
       }

        @RequestMapping(value="/updateTodos")
        public String updateTodos(@RequestParam String name,Model m)
        {

            m.addAttribute("paramcheck",name);
            log.info("parameter is : "+name);
            return "updateTodos";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/updateTodos",method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String finalUpdate(@RequestParam int id,@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam Object updateField, ModelMap mp)
        {
            List<Todo> to = todd.retrieveToDo();
            List<Todo> newTodo=to.stream().filter(i->i.getId()==id).map(v->{
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("Desc"))
                {
                    v.setDesc((String)updateField);
                }
                else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("user"))
                {
                    v.setUser((String)updateField);
                }
                else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("status"))
                {
                    v.setDone(updateField.equals("active")?true:false);
                }
                return v;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            log.debug("list :"+newTodo);
            System.out.println("list "+newTodo);
            System.out.println("coming to update todo controller");
            mp.put("td",newTodo);
            return "redirect:/listtodos";
        }
    }
```

Below is the jsp page where i am displaying all the list of todos .

listtodos.jsp

```
<%@ include file="common/header.jspf"%>
<%@ include file="common/navigation.jspf"%>
<div class ="container">
<font color ="blue">${message}</font>
<table class ="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th style ="color:blue">User Id</th>
    <th style ="color:blue">User Name</th>
    <th style ="color:blue">Description</th>
    <th style ="color:blue">Date</th>
     <th style ="color:blue">Status</th>
     <th style ="color:blue">Delete</th>
     <th style ="color:blue">Update</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
<c:forEach items = "${td}" var="s">
<td>${s.getId()}</td>
<td>${s.getUser()}</td>
<td>${s.getDesc()}</td>
<td><d:formatDate value ="${s.getDate()}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/></td>
<td>${s.isDone()}</td>
<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-warning" href="/delete?id=${s.getId()}"/>Delete</td>
<td><a type ="button" class="btn btn-success" href="/update?id=${s.getId()}"/>Update</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<div><a href ="/addTodo">Add new todo </a></div>
<%--<div><a href ="/deleteTodo">Delete Todo</a></div>--%>
<%@ include file="common/footer.jspf"%>
```

Update todo where i am giving choice to the user what he wants to update and todo id i am passing from list todo.jsp

UpdateTodo.jsp

```
<html>
<title>
Login Application
</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<div class="container">
What do you want to update :
<a type ="button" href="/updateTodos?name=user&id=${registerId}">User</a>
<a type ="button" href="/updateTodos?name=desc&id=${registerId}">Description</a>
<a type ="button" href="/updateTodos?name=date&id=${registerId}">Date</a>
<a type ="button" href="/updateTodos?name=status&id=${registerId}">Status</a>
</div>
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


update todos jsp where i am actually updating something in the todo
```

updateTodos.jsp

```
<html>
<title>
Login Application
</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<script>
console.log("coming to jsp");
</script
<form method="post">
<div class="container">
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label>Enter the ${paramcheck}:</label>
<input type="text" name="updateField"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="update"/>
</fieldset>
</div>
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</form>
</body>
</html>

Below is pom.xml i am using for this project

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Mayur</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringLoginApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>default</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.26.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But when i am clicking on update.It is not hitting my update request in todo controller.

Comment: define the form action `<form action="/update" method="post">`

Comment: Tried that also but that is also not working.

Comment: On a second look  the action should be `/updateTodos`. By not working , what exactly happens ?

Comment: I am not matching with the action .Since i am sending a post request method so it should match.It is not not giving any error also .

Comment: I suggested `/updateTodos` based on the parameters . Without request mapping I don't understand how the request would reach a required controller method. What happens when you hit with the url (say `http://localhost:8080/update`) from any browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/update when i hit this it is going to updateTodo.jsp After that i am giving choice to the user what they want to update.Suppose im clicking user ,so it update the user in the todo.When i enter the value for user ,i am expecting to forward  the request to (value="/updateTodos",method = RequestMethod.POST),that is not working

Comment: I have mentioned name also

Comment: Fixes required : 1. have all the required request parameters in the form ( name ,id ,updateField ) 2. redirect to `listtodos` will result in a loop  . Suggestions : Have Wrapper classes as parameter types ( example Integer instead of int ). Most of the handler method returns will loop back to itself.